Displaying filtered web-socket data on html page
Apologies, I'm pretty new to Jquery and websockets but I feel like I'm grasping enough of it where I should be close to getting my simple script to work.
All I'm trying to do is display filtered data on a webpage from a websocket. The filter should only display any data that starts with an "S,".
I can see that the websocket is connected in Dev tools and that unfiltered data is flowing but nothing is being displayed on the page.

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    const socket = new WebSocket('wss://proxy.livemadisonalerts.com/');

    socket.onmessage = function(event) {
        const data = event.data;
        if (data.startsWith('S,')) {
            $('#output').append('<p>' + data + '</p>');
        }
    };
});
</script>

<div id="output">TEST OUTPUT</div>


My example page is: https://livemadisonalerts.com/?page_id=50

That endpoint seems to be returning values starting with 'K' and not 'S'.
I was able to run your code (using React instead of Jquery), and the websocket piece works fine.
if (data.startsWith('K,')) {
  console.log('true', { data })
  // display to page (using Jquery instead of this line if you prefer)
  document.getElementsByTagName('header')[0].innerHTML += data
}

Are you able to see a debugging statement inside your data.startsWith('S,') condition?
